# Java DOM and SAX parsers

Tags: java, dom, saxparser, domparser

Could anyone help me with this Question? Implement Java DOM and SAX parsers to display the contents of nodes a) color_swatch along with its attribute of  of all catalog_item Typesb) price of all catalogue items (use the following file:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<?xml-stylesheet href="catalog.xsl" type="text/xsl"?>
<!DOCTYPE catalog SYSTEM "catalog.dtd">
<catalog>
<product description="Cardigan Sweater" product_image="cardigan.jpg">
<catalog_item Type="Men's">
<item_number>QWZ5671</item_number>
<price>39.95</price>
<size description="Medium">
<color_swatch image="red_cardigan.jpg">Red</color_swatch>
<color_swatch image="burgundy_cardigan.jpg">Burgundy</color_swatch>
</size>
<size description="Large">
<color_swatch image="red_cardigan.jpg">Red</color_swatch>
<color_swatch image="burgundy_cardigan.jpg">Burgundy</color_swatch>
</size>
</catalog_item>
<catalog_item Type="Women's">
<item_number>RRX9856</item_number>
<price>42.50</price>
<size description="Small">
<color_swatch image="red_cardigan.jpg">Red</color_swatch>
<color_swatch image="navy_cardigan.jpg">Navy</color_swatch>
<color_swatch image="burgundy_cardigan.jpg">Burgundy</color_swatch>
</size>
<size description="Medium">
<color_swatch image="red_cardigan.jpg">Red</color_swatch>
<color_swatch image="navy_cardigan.jpg">Navy</color_swatch>
<color_swatch image="burgundy_cardigan.jpg">Burgundy</color_swatch>
<color_swatch image="black_cardigan.jpg">Black</color_swatch>
</size>
<size description="Large">
<color_swatch image="navy_cardigan.jpg">Navy</color_swatch>
<color_swatch image="black_cardigan.jpg">Black</color_swatch>
</size>
<size description="Extra Large">
<color_swatch image="burgundy_cardigan.jpg">Burgundy</color_swatch>
<color_swatch image="black_cardigan.jpg">Black</color_swatch>
</size>
</catalog_item>
<catalog_item Type="BabyGirls">
<item_number>ABC1234</item_number>
<price>30.00</price>
<size description="Small">
<color_swatch image="red_cardigan.jpg"></color_swatch>
</size>
<size description="Medium">
<color_swatch image="pink_cardigan.jpg"></color_swatch>
</size>
<size description="Large">
<color_swatch image="blue_cardigan.jpg"></color_swatch>
</size>
<size description="Extra Large">
<color_swatch image="orange_cardian.jpg"></color_swatch>
</size>
</catalog_item>
<catalog_item Type="BabyBoys">
<item_number>BCD4321</item_number>
<price>30.00</price>
<size description="Small">
<color_swatch image="black_cardigan.jpg"></color_swatch>
</size>
<size description="Medium">
<color_swatch image="grey_cardigan.jpg"></color_swatch>
</size>
<size description="Large">
<color_swatch image="blue_cardigan.jpg"></color_swatch>
</size>
<size description="Extra Large">
<color_swatch image="navy_cardigan.jpg"></color_swatch>
</size>
</catalog_item>
</product>
</catalog>
```

Comment: This is not a "do my work for me" site, and "can anybody help" is not a valid question.

Comment: For more on this, please read: [Why is “Can someone help me?” not an actual question?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/284236)